# How can i get this do repeat function to work in SPSS

Tags: loops, repeat, spss

I have written a piece of syntax to identify whether AB has been used for an AE type or not. However when I run the syntax it says that it did not work and it is driving me crazy. Does someone know how to do this? I have made sure that all variables are next to each other in the data, so that should not be the problem.

```
do repeat AE_trial_numberedN = AE_trial_numberedN1 to AE_trial_numberedN134 / Start_med = Start_med1 to Start_med39 / i_aestdt = i_aestdt1 to  i_aestdt134 / i_aeendt = i_aeendt1 to i_aeendt134 /
ABused= ABused1 to ABused39 / AB_AE_reln = AB_AE_reln1 to AB_AE_reln134.

    do if (AE_trial_numberedN=1 & start_med >  i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused > 0).  
    compute  AB_AE_reln=1.  
    
    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=1 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused = 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=11.  
    
    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=2 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused > 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=2.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=2 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused = 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=12.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=3 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused > 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=3.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=3 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused = 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=13.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=4 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused > 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=4.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=4 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused = 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=14.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=5 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused > 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=5.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=5 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused = 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=15.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=6 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused > 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=6.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=6 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused = 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=16.

    else if ( AE_trial_numberedN=7|AE_trial_numberedN=8|AE_trial_numberedN=9    |   AE_trial_numberedN=10|AE_trial_numberedN=11|AE_trial_numberedN=12   |   AE_trial_numberedN=13|AE_trial_numberedN=14 |AE_trial_numberedN=15  |   AE_trial_numberedN=16|AE_trial_numberedN=17 |AE_trial_numberedN=18  |   AE_trial_numberedN=19|AE_trial_numberedN=20 |AE_trial_numberedN=21  |   AE_trial_numberedN=22 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused > 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=7.

    else if (AE_trial_numberedN=7|AE_trial_numberedN=8|AE_trial_numberedN=9 |   AE_trial_numberedN=10|AE_trial_numberedN=11|AE_trial_numberedN=12   |   AE_trial_numberedN=13|AE_trial_numberedN=14 |AE_trial_numberedN=15  |   AE_trial_numberedN=16|AE_trial_numberedN=17 |AE_trial_numberedN=18  |   AE_trial_numberedN=19|AE_trial_numberedN=20 |AE_trial_numberedN=21  |   AE_trial_numberedN=22 & start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt and ABused = 0).
    compute  AB_AE_reln=17.

    end if.
    end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the content of your `do if` like this:

```
do if start_med > i_aestdt & start_med < i_aeendt & and ABused >= 0.
recode AE_trial_numberedN (1 thr 6=copy)(7 thr 21=7) into AB_AE_reln.
if ABused = 0 AB_AE_reln=AB_AE_reln+1.
end if.
```

On the other hand, your `do repeat` can not work, since all lists of variables have to have the same lengths, and yours have 134 for some and 39 for others. It looks like the output you need is more complex than just `AB_AE_reln1 to AB_AE_reln134`, so you'll have to decide how it really should look and then get it through creating some nested loops. You can get some guidance [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/do-repeat-and-loop-when-use-what) on nested loops, and examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258160/spss-syntax-nested-loop-of-variables-within-do-repeat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277232/spss-syntax-recode-in-nested-loop) on using SPSS macro for nesting loops.